# Google Chrome updated and broke my website's ajax/jquery/json/something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-chrome

http://www.fennux.com/market

The latest Google Chrome update broke my website for literally every user that updated. I don't know what happened. Does anyone have an idea?

The issue is - when you click one of the drop down boxes and click an option... the moment you click anywhere else it tries to add an additional tag. It shouldn't, but it does.

This worked fine a week ago. I'm not good with json/ajax/jquery/javscript etc so I don't even know where to begin.

```
    $('.select-group select').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width() + 30);

    $(this).bind('change', function() {
        $(this).after('<p>' + $(this).find(':selected').text() + '<span>X</span></p>');
        $(this).next().hide().slideDown();
        $(this).find(':selected').remove();

        parentFrameResize();
    });
});
```

that is the part that creats the "Tags" after each time a select option is clicked... it's creating it fine, and then if you click ANYWHERE else on the page it creates a second tag, maybe on "deselect" or something? It makes no sense.

Comment: Look at the changes made on the for the newest chrome update

Comment: Also most of the time you want to try and find exactly where the problem is then post the code containing the problem generic questions like this is not what stackoverflow was designed for.

Comment: i don't know where the problem lies, that's the issue, else I would put exactly that. I'll even post a few snippets now to see if it'll help but, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a user blur after a change to the selectbox is firing the 'change' event. The fix seems to be to blur the select before removing the option.

```
$(this).bind('change', function() {
    $(this).after('<p>' + $(this).find(':selected').text() + '<span>X</span></p>');
    $(this).next().hide().slideDown();
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).find(':selected').remove();

    parentFrameResize();
});
```